# Animate child element for target parent from list of elements with same animation trigger Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a list of DIVs generated with the *ngFor directive with the same animation trigger.

I need to animate a child DIV of a target parent div on hover with angular, it keeps animating the child div of all the other DIVs even when it's not the target.

How do I make it work? This is my Template

```
<article class="row works">
        <div *ngFor="let work of works" class="col-4 work" (mouseenter)="dActivator($event)" (mouseleave)="dActivator(work.title + 'leave')">
            <img [src]="work.postal" class="img-fluid" alt="..." />
            <div class="title" [@showWork]="activateAnim">
                <h3>{{work.title}}</h3>
                <a [href]="work.link"><span><img src="/assets/images/eye.png" alt="..." /></span></a>
                <a [href]="work.link"><span><img src="/assets/images/link.png" alt="..." /></span></a>
                <a [href]="work.link"><span><img src="/assets/images/share.png" alt="..." /></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

The animation code

```
     animations: [
      trigger('showWork', [
       state('show', style({
        top: "55%",
      })),
      state('hide', style({
        top: "100%",
      })),
      transition('* => show', [
      animate(500, keyframes([
        style({top: "100%", transform: 'scale(.6)', offset: 0}),
        style({top: "55%", transform: 'scale(1.05)', offset: 0.7}),
        style({transform: 'scale(1.0)', offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ]),
    transition('show => hide', [
      animate(500, keyframes([
        style({transform: 'scale(1.0)', offset: 0}),
        style({top: "55%", transform: 'scale(1.05)', offset: 0.3}),
        style({top: "100%", transform: 'scale(0.6)', offset: 1.0})
      ]))
    ])
  ])
]
```

And the dActivator function

```
dActivator($which){

if($which == "enter"){
  this.delay = setTimeout(()=>{
    this.activateAnim = "show";
   }, 500);
 }
if($which == "leave"){
    clearTimeout(this.delay);
   this.activateAnim = "hide";
  }

}
```

How do I make the animation for a child of only the target div. Trying to avoid jQuery as much as possible.

Comment: It's been more than a week now, and no response....Guess I can't implement what i want yet with angular animation..